# how can i using 2 INSERT INTO statement to store different data

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have these two sql statements. But while executing,it show 'Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement.'

```
Dim sqlString As String
        sqlString = "INSERT INTO CreditCardRecord(CustomerEmail, CardholderName, 
                     CreditCardNo, CCExpMonth, CCExpYear, CVCNo, CardIssuingBank, 
                     Amount) VALUES ('" & Master.cEmailDOnMasterPage & "','" & 
                     cardholderName & "','" & creditCardNo & "','" & ccExpMonth & "',
                     '" & ccExpYesr & "','" & cvc & "','" & cardIssuingBank & "',
                     '" & totalamount & "')"
        Dim sqlcommand As New OleDbCommand(sqlString, db)
        sqlcommand.ExecuteNonQuery()

Dim customerRervation As String
        customerRervation = "INSERT INTO CustomerReservation(CustomerEmail, 
                             CustomerFN, CustomerLN, CustomerIdentityCard, 
                             CustomerPhoneNo, Package, Table, Amount, BookingDate)  
                             VALUSE ('" & Master.cEmailDOnMasterPage & "',
                             '" & customerFN & "','" & customerLN & "',
                             '" & customerIC & "','" & customerPhoneNo & "',
                             '" & lblShowPackage.Text & "','" & lblShowTable.Text & 
                             "','" & totalamount & "','" & lblShowDate.Text & "')"
       Dim sqlcommand2 As New OleDbCommand(customerRervation, db)
        sqlcommand2.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

Comment: In the second statement you have `VALUSE` instead of `VALUES`. Maybe that's the issue?

Comment: After i change the VALUES, still have Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement. At line sqlcommand2.ExecuteNonQuery()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue in your 2nd sql query statement. You are wrongly spelled VALUES to VALUSE. so instead of VALUSE, use VALUES.

```
Dim customerRervation As String
        customerRervation = "INSERT INTO CustomerReservation(CustomerEmail, 
                             CustomerFN, CustomerLN, CustomerIdentityCard, 
                             CustomerPhoneNo, Package, Table, Amount, BookingDate)  
                             VALUES ('" & Master.cEmailDOnMasterPage & "',
                             '" & customerFN & "','" & customerLN & "',
                             '" & customerIC & "','" & customerPhoneNo & "',
                             '" & lblShowPackage.Text & "','" & lblShowTable.Text & 
                             "','" & totalamount & "','" & lblShowDate.Text & "')"
       Dim sqlcommand2 As New OleDbCommand(customerRervation, db)
        sqlcommand2.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

Comment: After i change the VALUES, still have Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement. At line sqlcommand2.ExecuteNonQuery()

Comment: your first query is working? The best way to resolve this is to debug it. Put a breakpoint before execute line. and take the  value of "customerRervation" variable. then try to execute this value directly in your databse (sql server management studio). then you can straightforward, get what the issue in query during execution.

Comment: my first query can store in database, when i add second query it show Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement. but the first query able to store in db. 
When i try remove first query, only have second query also same error.

Comment: Can you include your database column types? may be the some of column required integer value and you are sending string value to database. if some column are integer, then instead of '" & columnName & "', use " & columnName & ". Are you able to debug it, what I told in previous comment

Comment: the breakpoint to debug i not understand. All i use string, in db CustomerEmail, CustomerFN, CustomerLN, CustomerIdentityCard, Package and BookingDate use Text datatype, CustomerPhoneNo, Table and Amount use Number datatype.

Answer (score 0):

Just add [] can already

Dim customerRervation As String
        customerRervation = "INSERT INTO CustomerReservation([CustomerEmail], 
                             [CustomerFN], [CustomerLN], [CustomerIdentityCard], 
                             [CustomerPhoneNo], [Package], [Table], [Amount], [BookingDate])
                             VALUES ('" & Master.cEmailDOnMasterPage & "',
                             '" & customerFN & "','" & customerLN & "',
                             '" & customerIC & "','" & customerPhoneNo & "',
                             '" & lblShowPackage.Text & "','" & lblShowTable.Text & 
                             "','" & totalamount & "','" & lblShowDate.Text & "')"
       Dim sqlcommand2 As New OleDbCommand(customerRervation, db)
        sqlcommand2.ExecuteNonQuery()